# My Int() always returns 0s?

Tags: java, android

Im having problems with this...
Note that tip.setText tells me that it's higher than 0.
I will also call getResults method in another class. (Int 'correct' is already higher than 0)

I'd like to know why correct is always 0 in getResults and how can I fix that?

```
     public int correct = 0;

    private String[] questions =
   {"Question 1", 
    "Question 2",
    "Question 3", 
    "Question 4",
    "Question 5"
    };

public void onClick(View view) {
        if (alive == false) {
        //  startActivity(new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END"));
            return;
        }
        try {
        button_click = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click);
        button_click.start();
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.button5: //main
            break;
        case R.id.button1: //answer_1
            if(correct(1))
                correct++;


            break;
        case R.id.button2: //answer_2
            if(correct(2))
                correct++;

            break;
        case R.id.button3: //answer_3
            if(correct(3))
                correct++;

            break;
        case R.id.button4: //answer_3
            if(correct(4))
                correct++;


            break;

        default:
            break;


        }
        Game(i1);
        tip.setText("Correct answers "+correct); //this thing tells me that it's not 0. (Well, in the beggining it's 0, but after counter goes up! (correct++)
        } catch (Exception ex){}
    }

    public int getResults(){
        return (int)(correct*5)/(questions.length+1);
    }
```

EDIT:

```
public class ETBetaActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button answer_1,
    answer_2,answer_3,
    answer_4,main;

    TextView q_textview,
    tip;

    private String a1,a2,a3,a4 = "";

    private int i1 = 0;
    public float correct = 0;

    private boolean alive = true;

    MediaPlayer button_click;

    private String[] questions =
   {"Question 1", 
    "Question 2",
    "Question 3", 
    "Question 4",
    "Question 5"
    };
    private String[] answers_correct =
   {"Correct answer 1",
    "Correct answer 2",
    "Correct answer 3", 
    "Correct answer 4",
    "Correct answer 5"
    };

    private String[][] answers_wrong = 
    { {"Incorrect answer 1-1", "Incorrect answer 1-2" , "Incorrect answer 1-3"},
      {"Incorrect answer 2-1", "Incorrect answer 2-2" , "Incorrect answer 2-3"},
      {"Incorrect answer 3-1", "Incorrect answer 3-2" , "Incorrect answer 3-3"},
      {"Incorrect answer 4-1", "Incorrect answer 4-2" , "Incorrect answer 4-3"},
      {"Incorrect answer 5-1", "Incorrect answer 5-2" , "Incorrect answer 5-3"},


    };


    List<String> question_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> answer_list_correct = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getData();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (alive == false) {
        //  startActivity(new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END"));
            return;
        }
        try {
        button_click = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click);
        button_click.start();
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.button5: //main
            break;
        case R.id.button1: //answer_1
            if(correct(1))
                correct++;


            break;
        case R.id.button2: //answer_2
            if(correct(2))
                correct++;

            break;
        case R.id.button3: //answer_3
            if(correct(3))
                correct++;

            break;
        case R.id.button4: //answer_3
            if(correct(4))
                correct++;


            break;

        default:
            break;


        }
        Game(i1);
        correct++;
        tip.setText("Correct answers "+correct);
        } catch (Exception ex){}
    }


    public float getResults(){
        return (Float)(correct*5)/(questions.length);
    }

    private boolean correct(int button){
        for (int i = 0; i < answers_correct.length; i++){
        if(button == 1 && a1 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 2 && a2 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 3 && a3 == answers_correct[i]
            || button == 4 && a4 == answers_correct[i])
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void Game(int q){
        try {
        if(i1 >= questions.length) { //no more questions
            startActivity(new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END"));
            alive = false;
            return;
        }

        main.setText("Next");
        String answer_list[][] = {
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]},
                {answers_correct[i1], answers_wrong[q][0] , answers_wrong[q][1] , answers_wrong[q][2]}
        };

        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(answer_list[q]));
        answer_1.setText(answer_list[q][0]);
        answer_2.setText(answer_list[q][1]);
        answer_3.setText(answer_list[q][2]);
        answer_4.setText(answer_list[q][3]);
        a1 = answer_list[q][0];
        a2 = answer_list[q][1];
        a3 = answer_list[q][2];
        a4 = answer_list[q][3];
        q_textview.setText(questions[q]);
        /*questions = question_list.toArray(new String[question_list.size()]);
        answers_correct = answer_list_correct.toArray(new String[answer_list_correct.size()]);
        question.setText(questions[i1]);        

        answer_list_correct.remove(questions[i1]);
        question_list.remove(questions[i1]);*/

        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        i1++;
    }
    private void getData(){
        //Getting the data
        main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        answer_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        answer_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        answer_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        answer_4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        q_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        tip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answ1);

        main.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_2.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_3.setOnClickListener(this);
        answer_4.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Resets the text
        //Note to self: Replace with another ContectView
        main.setText("Begin!");
        answer_4.setText("");
        answer_3.setText("");
        answer_2.setText("");
        answer_1.setText("");
        tip.setText("");

    /*  for(String x : questions) {
            for(String y : answers_correct){

            answer_list_correct.add(y);
            question_list.add(x);

            Collections.shuffle(answer_list_correct);
            Collections.shuffle(question_list);

            }
        } */



    }


    }
```

Another class

```
       public class End extends Activity implements RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener {
    ETBetaActivity classy = new ETBetaActivity();

    TextView score;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.end);
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        results();
        final RatingBar yourRating = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        yourRating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
              boolean fromUser) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              //  yourRating.setRating(rating);
                yourRating.setRating(classy.getResults());
              /*  Toast.makeText(End.this, "M:"+String.valueOf(rating),
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */
                Toast.makeText(End.this, "M "+classy.getResults(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});
     //movieImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);       
 }


    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
            boolean fromUser) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void results(){
        score.setText("Your mark  "+classy.getResults());
    }

    }
```

Comment: is correct 0 in `getResults()` or is `anInt` 0?

Comment: 'correct' is always 0, well.. and so is anInt.

Comment: What does `questions.length + 1` equal?

Comment: If correct is 0, the result of that expression will always be 0. What does it say correct is in `setText()`

Comment: You have both a method called correct() and a field called correct?

Comment: that method of yours, 'private boolean correct(int x)' is really confusing, consider giving it a prefix to make your code more readable - like isCorrect

Comment: When do you call `getResults()`, and what do you mean by you call it from another class?

Comment: As you already noticed, you're creating a new instance, hence the zero.

Answer (score 1):

When starting the End Activity you should do:

```
Intent end = new Intent("com.aleksei.etb.END");
end.putExtra("results", getResults());
startActivity(end);
```

And then remove the classy-field from your End-activity and instead read the results in the onCreate() method like:

```
int results = getIntExtra("results");
```

That will correctly transfer the results from one activity to the next.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that you are actually catching those cases in your switch statement. You may actually not be entering those cases.

Therefore, if you are not entering those cases `correct` will remain `0`

Comment: I am entering those cases. I have  tip.setText("Correct answers "+correct), to prove it. It tells me 'Correct answers <number> (not 0)'

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be doing integer division so if the size of questions is big the float divison would he 0.something an thus the integer division is 0. Try casting correct to float and you will get a decimal number instead

Comment: Still getting 0.0, even tho my tip.setText said '4' before getResults method was used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to figure out the answer to your problem real quick:

Turn

```
    public int correct = 0;
```

into a property

```
    private int _correct = 0;
    public int correct
    {
        get { return _correct; }
        set { _correct = value; }
    }
```

and set a break point on the setter.  Then you will see if something is setting it back to zero.  If nothing is ever setting it back to zero after it has been incremented then it's possible that maybe somewhere you are instantiating a new instance of your object and you don't realize that you're not working with a new instance with default values.

I don't think it's an integer division problem, and here's a note on that:

You are multiplying * 5, but then dividing by 5 (because there are 5 answers).  If the number of answers is going to change at some point, but the multiplier of 5 is going to remain the same then that makes sense.  But otherwise I don't know why you are doing that since 5/5 = 1 and it's kind of pointless to multiply something by one.

Comment: Im getting an average mark, ahh and yes! you're right! 2nd class 'ETBetaActivity classy = new ETBetaActivity();' which means Im resetting it back to 0! Darn, how stupid off me, any idea how can I still pass it into another class without resetting it?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that... but I'm glad I could help.  I thought that might be your problem :)

Comment: I made a simple android quiz game. Right now only 5 questions, and 4 answers. If you guess 5 times, your average is 5, if 4 it's 4... etc.. but when I'll add more questions. for example you've answered 10/25 questions. 10*5/25 = 2. (I need it to be 1-5)

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to do?  You want to pass an existing ETBetaActivity object into another ETBetaActivity object?  Not sure why you don't just use the existing one instead of creating a new one.  Unfortunately I gotta run right now but maybe if you post a new question someone else can help you figure that part out.  Good luck!

Comment: @MisterSquonk Yeah I honestly didn't even realize I was looking at Java code until just now.  I don't know Java so feel free to edit my answer to reflect Java code if you want.